# Perl "lwp-request" giving error 500 using TLS 1.2

Tags: perl, unix, tls1.2, lwp

We've been using a shipping API via our Unix server, specifically SCO Openserver 5.0.7, for a little over a year.

Our system generates XML files, sends them to the server using the [`lwp-request` command](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/bin/lwp-request), receives the response, interprets it, and processes it as needed by our system.

The exact command we use is:

```
lwp-request -m POST https://url.com < REQUESTFILE.XML > RESPONSEFILE.XML
```

The shipping company is upgrading all servers to require TLS 1.2, and now I get

> 500 SSL negotiation failed:

as a response when using this command.

I'm not sure how to go about making our system compatible.

- Do I need to update Perl? (Current version is v5.8.8 built for i586-pc-sco3.2v5.0). If so, what is the minimum version to use TLS 1.2?
- Do I need to update LWP? I believe my LWP version is 5.805 (got this using `perl -MLWP -le "print(LWP->VERSION)"`)
- Do I need to go into the `lwp-request` script and manually modify it?
- Or is there perhaps another command that does an equivalent job using TLS 1.2?

Comment: I'm afraid you need to do some more debugging before we can help. That `SSL negotiation failed` is suspicious, as it's a common problem that the required SSL module isn't installed. Do you know any Perl at all? Presumably this isn't something that you want to let us test ourselves?

Comment: Hi Borodin,Unfortunately I do not know Perl at all, though I know other languages and dont mind trying to figure it out.
You mentioned a required SSL module not being installed. Do you happen to know what module that might be? I don't mind providing some more info if it will help others test and come up with a solution. What other info would you need?

Comment: Regarding the updates, I would say that it's unlikely that an upgrade would fix your problems, but it's always nice to be on the same page as others whom you engage for help. The latest version of LWP is 6.15, and Perl v5.8.8 was released over ten years ago on 31-Jan-2006. So it certainly wouldn't do any harm, and it may make it easier to find a resolution, but don't expect it to fix anything.

Comment: No, not for sure, but [IO::Socket::SSL](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::SSL) is a good bet. But I'd much rather debug this than update some things and hope. I suggest that you google "Perl TLS 1.2" as there's a *lot* there that should help.

Comment: Is it possible that v5.8.8 is the latest version of Perl for SCO 5.0.7?
and do you know if LWP 6.15 supports TLS 1.2?
If so, do you think I would have to modify the LWP-REQUEST script manually in order to force it to TLS 1.2?

Comment: So then I need to install the IO::Socket:SSL module, and then modify the LWP-REQUEST script to add this functionality manually?

Comment: *"Is it possible that v5.8.8 is the latest version of Perl for SCO 5.0.7?"* It's highly unlikely. If there are no repercussions then you should go straight for v5.24. The Perl team are exceptionally hot on backward-compatability and you should see very few issues. And I really can't tell what you should do, I'm sorry. I have almost no information, and presumably you can't let me connect and test myself?

Comment: Probably not, but perhaps i can provide you with the connection details and a sample file to try and test with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your very old version of Perl (5.8.8, where 5.8.9 was release 2008) and LWP (5.805, 5.806 was released 2007) on a very old OS (SCO OpenServer 5.0.7, last update around 2009) it is likely that you are also running a very old version of OpenSSL. TLS 1.2 was only specified in 2008 and got available in OpenSSL only with 1.0.1 which was released 03/2012, i.e. several years after any software updates to your system.

You can check it it with `openssl version` and my guess is that it says something about version 0.9.8, i.e. way too old.

To make TLS 1.2 work on this old system you would need to compile a newer version of OpenSSL (at least the latest 1.0.1) and rebuild the Perl modules interfacing with OpenSSL so that they use this new version. Depending on your setup this might be Crypt::SSLeay or Net::SSLeay. And given how old your system  is it is not unlikely that you run in various problems with compiling simply because most don't expect that somebody tries to compile newer software on outdated systems. Thus it might just be easier to upgrade everything to a recent and supported OS instead of trying to fight with an old system.

Comment: Hi Steffen,thanks for the detailed response!
I checked, and our OpenSSL version is 0.9.7i.
We are currently in talks to update our system, but I have a feeling that the costs will be too high to migrate to a newer OS.

So if i update OpenSSL, and then I update Perl and LWP as well, would the newer LWP incorporate the newer OpenSSL? or do i need to go into the script anyways and modify it myself to use Crypt:SSLeay or Net::SSLeay?
Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @scohenr: LWP uses Net::SSLeay or Crypt::SSLeay (probably Crypt::SSLeay in case of your old LWP). If this \*::SSLeay library is linked with the newer openssl than LWP will automatically pick this up.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Is there any way I can verify which *::SSLeay library is being used, and whether it is linked?

Comment: To find out which \*::SSLeay library is loaded check %INC once you've tried to access a https URL. Then you will find either `$INC{'Net/SSLeay.pm'}` or  `$INC{'Crypt/SSLeay.pm'}`  set. How the linked version is checked depends on the module but you can also use `strace` to see where libssl.so is loaded from.

Comment: Forgive me but I'm new to most of this, so I'm not sure where I'm supposed to run the commands you listed. Am I supposed to modify the lwp-request script and put the %INC or strace commands in there? Or do I run strace from the command prompt before I execute the lwp-request command?

Comment: @scohenr: check http://pastebin.com/rTm7GnGN for code. As for strace - try `strace -e open perl your-code.pl 2>&1 | grep libssl`

Comment: ok, so i took the sample code from the page you sent, saved it in a file, and then tried to execute it using the strace command, and I got no result.
Should i have gotten a result? Or should i be trying this with my `"lwp-request -m POST https://url.com < REQUESTFILE.XML > RESPONSEFILE.XML"` command?

Comment: @scohenr: no, you should simple execute this file with perl to first find out if you use Crypt::SSLeay or Net::SSLeay. The strace is for your code, not for the pastebin code. But even then it should work with the pastebin code too. If you did not get any result then you might have no libssl.so on your system. In any case - the strace should be done to verify that you are using the new library which you obviously not do (did you even compile a new openssl?)

Comment: No i have not compiled a new openssl yet. 
I took your advice and executed the pastebin script by itself, and i got `using Crypt::SSLeay with unknown openssl version`.
Based on this, do you think LWP would automatically pick it up?
What would be my best course of action from here? I'm honestly not sure how to compile/install a new openssl version. 
Thanks again for all your help!!

Comment: @scohenr: your best choice would be to get a current system and avoid all these problems. If not you will find enough information online on how to compile openssl and perl.

Comment: Great! Thanks again for all your help! I really appreciate it!